# Announcement app?

Tags: sharepoint-server, app

Does anyone know of a good Announcements app that works as a good substitute for the OOTB Sharepoint 2013 one? We have several people who post, and the formatting is very inconsistent. Really all we need is something that has a preview function and ideally something that will truncate the posts, like what you'd see on a blog.

Answer (score 0):

A sipme solution would be to turn on content approval in the announcement list, this way when the user saves it item, it can be seen by only those with high enough permission. This will allow them to view it and go back and make changes. Once done, it can be approved and everyone will see it.

Comment: I did try that, but it still wasn't quite what I wanted. The approval view doesn't really display the formatting how it will appear on the post. A formatting template would be really helpful.

Comment: Those with rights can see the announcement after it is submitted and verify the formatting. It isn't any different than publishing pages or blogs in Sharepoint.

Comment: You could maybe put in some Javascript on the New/Edit form to strip out html tags and clean it up a bit, might make it more consistent.